# DoCmd.SendObject email report with subreports

Tags: vba, ms-access, subreport

Two part question: 1. When I print my report, my subreports are not showing up. Is there a trick to this?
2. When I use the below code, it is giving me an error. I want to email the main report, with 2 subreports, on command click as a .pdf.

```
DoCmd.SendObject ([acSendReport],["AUS_Main"],[acFormatPDF],[heather@gmail.com],,,[AUS Checklist and Orders],["Sir/Ma'am,", & vbln "Attached is my AUS checklist. I have read and understand all information on this document, and will reach out to HRO if I have any unanswered questions."]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, entire report should be in PDF
2. Consider:

The [ ] characters are not needed. Nor is the single unpaired paren at beginning.

Email string needs to be in quotes.

Message concatenation is messed up.

vbln is not valid, use vbCrLf

```
DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, "AUS_Main", acFormatPDF, "heather@gmail.com", , , _
     "AUS Checklist and Orders", "Sir/Ma'am, " & vbCrLf & "Attached is my AUS checklist. I have read and understand all information on this document, and will reach out to HRO if I have any unanswered questions."
```

Comment: this gave me a compile error - expected: = ... could it be something wrong with my report?

Comment: Sorry, had a typo - paren not appropriate. See edited answer.